# My Mac freezes when using Safari

Tags: mac, safari, performance

I am using a Mac with OSX Snow Leopard. 
Sometimes I am playing some media through Safari and my Mac freezes. I basically cannot do anything. The trackpad does not work anymore as well as the keyboard. The only solution is to restart the system.

The question is:

Why the system suddenly freezes? Is the any way to prevent it? Or is there any way to avoid restarting the system every time?

Comment: Have you noticed this on a particular website? It could be that the site has some endless loop in the program. You can open up Activity Monitor before you browse, and see what happens when the computer freezes.

Comment: it does not happen every time I use safari. 
It usually happens on websites that run videos on Flash Player and have advertisements here and there (hate them...)

Comment: That does sound like more of a browser handling issue. I'd be curious if it does the same on FF or Chrome.

Comment: I have not gotten anything like that while using Chrome or FF

Comment: Doesn't surprise me. :) +1 to Adblock as well.

Comment: Might be the system running out of memory so it ends up swapping itself to death.  Try having Activity Viewer running when starting Flash so you can see what happens before it hangs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common Flash interaction issue (sounds like). I use the Safari extension ClickToFlash so I can control what Flash runs and when. And, I also use AdBlock to be sure those pesky side Ads don't bother me. You can still run Flash, but you have control and the freezing will hopefully stop.

Comment: Do I control what to run before executing? because when it freezes it's just impossible to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Like many others, I had some of those same issues on Lion (my computer would eventually become responsive - usually.)  What I did was delete Flash from my computer, and when you really, really want to use Flash, open the page in Chrome, which has Flash built in the browser.  If you enable the developer option in preferences (Preferences -> Advanced -> Show Develop menu in menu bar), you'll have a menu item for just such times.

You'll find a lot of sites have a fallback to HTML5 for the times Flash isn't available, but if it is, they'll use Flash.  This also has the added benefit of making web sites aware that people don't like Flash.